# Passing textbox control as argument

Tags: vb.net

The following code contains a function that retrieves values from database and places them in four textboxes for ex: txtCash, txtDebt, txtPayment, txtBalance. so instead of writing the textboxes inside the function, I want to replace them with placeholders and return the values to the form that contains these textboxes

```
Public Sub LoadTotals()
    Dim AfCashAmount As Double
    Dim AfDebtAmount As Double
    Dim AfPayment As Double

    Try
        sqL = "SELECT InvoiceID, SUM(InvoiceAmount) As Total FROM Invoice WHERE PaymentType = 'Cash' AND AccountType='AF' GROUP BY InvoiceID"
        ConnDB()
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sqL, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        AfCashAmount = 0

        Do While dr.Read = True
            AfCashAmount = AfCashAmount + dr(1)
        Loop

        '*************************************************************************

        sqL = "SELECT InvoiceID, SUM(InvoiceAmount) As Total FROM Invoice WHERE PaymentType = 'Debt' AND AccountType='AF' GROUP BY InvoiceID"
        ConnDB()
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sqL, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        AfDebtAmount = 0

        Do While dr.Read = True
            AfDebtAmount = AfDebtAmount + dr(1)
        Loop

        '*************************************************************************

        sqL = "SELECT PaymentID, SUM(PaymentAmount) FROM Payment WHERE Currency='AF' GROUP BY PaymentID"
        ConnDB()
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sqL, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        AfPayment = 0

        Do While dr.Read = True
            AfPayment = AfPayment + dr(1)
        Loop

        With frmStatistics
            .txtAFCash.Text = Format(AfCashAmount, "N2").ToString()
            .txtAFDebt.Text = Format(AfDebtAmount, "N2").ToString()
            .txtAFPayment.Text = Format(AfPayment, "N2").ToString()
            .txtAFBalance.Text = Format(AfDebtAmount - AfPayment, "N2").ToString()
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: And?  what's the problem?

Comment: Doesnt seem to be much point in that since those queries are getting specific values to be shown in specific controls.  Nothing gets abstracted.  Note that you create 3 DBCommand objects but only dispose of one.  Read up on `Using` blocks

Comment: @rory.ap i mentioned instead of writing the txtCash, txtDebt, txtPayment, txtBalance inside the function. i want to replace them with placeholders so that i can use the function with other forms too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following returning a Dictionary:

```
Public Function LoadTotals() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim AfCashAmount As Double
    Dim AfDebtAmount As Double
    Dim AfPayment As Double

    Try
        sqL = "SELECT InvoiceID, SUM(InvoiceAmount) As Total FROM Invoice WHERE PaymentType = 'Cash' AND AccountType='AF' GROUP BY InvoiceID"
        ConnDB()
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sqL, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        AfCashAmount = 0

        Do While dr.Read = True
            AfCashAmount = AfCashAmount + dr(1)
        Loop

        '*************************************************************************

        sqL = "SELECT InvoiceID, SUM(InvoiceAmount) As Total FROM Invoice WHERE PaymentType = 'Debt' AND AccountType='AF' GROUP BY InvoiceID"
        ConnDB()
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sqL, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        AfDebtAmount = 0

        Do While dr.Read = True
            AfDebtAmount = AfDebtAmount + dr(1)
        Loop

        '*************************************************************************

        sqL = "SELECT PaymentID, SUM(PaymentAmount) FROM Payment WHERE Currency='AF' GROUP BY PaymentID"
        ConnDB()
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sqL, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        AfPayment = 0

        Do While dr.Read = True
            AfPayment = AfPayment + dr(1)
        Loop

        'The following to return string values.
        Dim dictTotals As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        dictTotals.Add("CashAmount", Format(AfCashAmount, "N2").ToString())
        dictTotals.Add("DebtAmount", Format(AfDebtAmount, "N2").ToString())
        dictTotals.Add("Payment", Format(AfPayment, "N2").ToString())
        dictTotals.Add("Balance", Format(AfDebtAmount - AfPayment, "N2").ToString())

        ''The following to return the double values.
        ''In this case change the return value to Dictionary(Of String, Double)
        'Dim dictTotals As New Dictionary(Of String, Double)
        'dictTotals.Add("CashAmount", AfCashAmount)
        'dictTotals.Add("DebtAmount", AfDebtAmount)
        'dictTotals.Add("Payment", AfPayment)
        'dictTotals.Add("Balance",AfDebtAmount - AfPayment)

        Return dictTotals
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

So you can use the result on any other `Form` you want like the following:

```
Dim dictTotals As Dictionary(Of String, String) = LoadTotals()
txtAFCash.Text = dictTotals("CashAmount")
txtAFDebt.Text = dictTotals("DebtAmount")
txtAFPayment.Text = dictTotals("Payment")
txtAFBalance.Text = dictTotals("Balance")
```

Comment: instead of `Dictionary` you can introduce a class which will have property for totals.